# K8s - How trigger refresh of LoadBalancer svc IP?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using metallb to assign IPs to LoadBalancers in a home lab k8s cluster.  I've had to shrink the IP pool though as I need to use some of them in another test cluster.

I've done this but the IPs of the existing LB svcs have remained the same afterwards -- I need to give the LB svcs a kick somehow to get them to request new IPs.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the answer to your question is contained [in this github thread](https://github.com/metallb/metallb/issues/308).

Everything should come down to recreate your service with the appropriate configmap. Look at [this answer](https://github.com/metallb/metallb/issues/308#issuecomment-586580584):

**Before change**

```
[root@m-k8s ~]# kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)        AGE
cfgmap-svc   LoadBalancer   10.100.199.95   192.168.1.11   80:31463/TCP   2m5s
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>         443/TCP        4h13m
```

**Change IP address**

```
[root@m-k8s ~]# cat metallb-l2.yaml | grep 192.168
      - 192.168.1.11-192.168.1.13
[root@m-k8s ~]# sed -i 's/11/101/;s/13/103/' metallb-l2.yaml
[root@m-k8s ~]# cat metallb-l2.yaml | grep 192.168
      - 192.168.1.101-192.168.1.103
```

**Just apply**
`kubectl apply -f metallb-l2.yaml`

**Delete and revise by kubelet**

```
[root@m-k8s ~]# kubectl delete pods --all -n metallb-system
pod "controller-65895b47d4-l5xnn" deleted
pod "speaker-bk8gr" deleted
pod "speaker-bksns" deleted
pod "speaker-c2z6z" deleted
pod " speaker-chlt5" deleted
pod "speaker-scx6x" deleted
```

**Recreate svc**

```
[root@m-k8s ~]# kubectl delete service cfgmap-svc
service "cfgmap-svc" deleted
[root@m-k8s ~]# kubectl expose deployment cfgmap --type=LoadBalancer --name=cfgmap-svc --port=80
service/cfgmap-svc exposed
```

**Check svc**

```
[root@m-k8s ~]# kubectl get svc
NAME          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
cfgmap-svc3   LoadBalancer   10.104.192.184   192.168.1.101   80:31440/TCP   8s
kubernetes    ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>          443/TCP        4h34m
```

You can also look [at this github issue](https://github.com/metallb/metallb/issues/348). Note, it is old thread.

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction.   In fact all I had to do was delete the pods (I'd already updated the configmap).  
`kubectl -n metallb delete pod --all`  
The services all obtained new IPs from the new pool once the new metallb pods were running.